# programmatically hide Bootstrap accordion

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

In my code I use a bootstrap accordion for extra option. When click start, I want to collapse (close) it. I tried

```
    $('#accordion2').collapse({
        hide: true
    });
```

But the accordion close and then reopen. A second click do not do anything more. What I miss here? As written in the Bootstrap documentation I use the data-parent to close it.
The code is:

```
  <div id="accordion2" style="width:802px;">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingImgOne">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseImgOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseImgOne">
              Testrun Optionen
            </button>
          </h5>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseImgOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingImgOne" data-parent="#accordion2">
          <div class="card-body">

             <div class="form-group row">
               <label for="text" class="col-4 col-form-label">Server</label>
               <div class="col-7">
                 <div class="input-group">

                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="c06" id="c06" checked> <span class="label-text">c06</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="c07" id="c07" checked> <span class="label-text">c07</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="c08" id="c08" checked> <span class="label-text">c08</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="c09" id="c09"> <span class="label-text">c09</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="c10" id="c10"> <span class="label-text">c10</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="c11" id="c11"> <span class="label-text">c11</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="c12" id="c12"> <span class="label-text">c12</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="c13" id="c13"> <span class="label-text">c13</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="c14" id="c14"> <span class="label-text">c14</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="c15" id="c15"> <span class="label-text">c15</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="c16" id="c16"> <span class="label-text">c16</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="c17" id="c17"> <span class="label-text">c17</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group row">
               <label for="select" class="col-4 col-form-label">Server Domain</label>
               <div class="col-7">
                 <select id="imgdomain" name="select" class="custom-select">
                      <option value="domain.com" selected>domain.com</option>
                 </select>
               </div>
             </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<br/>
```

Comment: can you show us your complete html code?

Comment: I have added the part for the accordion.